# DB error: Unknown error in search

Tags: wordpress, drupal, search, search-results, custom-search

Using both WP & Drupal with different databases.

CiviCRM version : 4.6.28 
Drupal version 7.54
Wordpress version :4.7.4

I am trying to use the search option given in CiviCRM. It fails in both WP & drupal with " Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: Unknown error"

why this issue is seen? What is the solution?

========================================================

```
#0 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
#4 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
#5 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1055 ** Expression #37 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains ...")
#7 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
#9 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
#10 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
#11 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(321): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
#12 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(1181): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...", TRUE)
#13 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\BAO\Query.php(4685): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
#14 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\Selector.php(550): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->getCachedContacts("civicrm search b941cfc8ff1839fc77f5e89495a28257_3756", 0, 50, FALSE)
#15 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Selector\Controller.php(403): CRM_Contact_Selector->getRows(4, 0, 50, Object(CRM_Utils_Sort), 1, NULL)
#16 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Selector\Controller.php(340): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->getRows(Object(CRM_Contact_Selector_Controller))
#17 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\Form\Search.php(876): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->run()
#18 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\Form\Search\Advanced.php(330): CRM_Contact_Form_Search->postProcess()
#19 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Form.php(345): CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Advanced->postProcess()
#20 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\QuickForm\Action\Refresh.php(75): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#21 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Refresh->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Advanced), "refresh")
#22 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Advanced), "refresh")
#23 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("refresh")
#24 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:4), (Array:0))
#25 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#26 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#27 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm.php(1196): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#28 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#29 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#30 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#31 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#32 C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-admin\admin.php(222): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#33 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have mysql full group by mode on - 4.7 supports that (latest version is 4.7.19) but not 4.6. I think full group by is on by default or always on mysql 5.7

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Comment: cool !! thanks a lot.  I was just frustrated with many reports giving the same error... was worried much on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on debugging you should get more information about the error & people will hopefully be able to interpret it for you - under Administer->System Settings->debugging and Error handling. Turn on debugging and backtrace.

Comment: Thanks, how do I share the error report... I am not seeing any option to attach files